# Centering PyQt window in main.py

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to learn PyQt5 basics and currently having trouble with understanding how to set up multiple windows (actually widgets). I have many .py files with different forms I've created with QtDesigner. Windows set up just fine, but I don't know how to center them automatically. This is my main.py file (which I also don't fully understand, but it works):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

import menu

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, menu.menuForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the beginning of my menuForm class:

```
class menuForm(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(901, 616)
    Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    Form.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
    [...]
```

I've found some tutorials about window centering in PyQt but none of them helped, because there always is just a single window. I'm not even sure if I should try to center it in the main.py file, or rather in every form class I've got.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Centered to what?

Comment: By centered I meant placed in the middle of a screen.

Comment: You cannot automatically center *every* new window, you have to implement the logic based on the answers in the duplicated question. Note: You're inheriting from QMainWindow, but your ui class is for QWidget ("form"). You either subclass from QWidget, or you create your UI in Designer using an actual main window.